# Trying to start Cisco packet tracer

Tags: cisco

So I'm trying to install packet tracer and it says that is successfully installed

[image]

and to type "packettracer" in terminal to start Cisco packet tracer. But nothing happens. I would be really grateful if someone tell me how to start it :D :)

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/pack*`into your post or better yet `sudo find / -name packettracer` output

Comment: I tried to find it with sudo find and it says that there is no such file :/

Comment: At teh risk of repeating myself, Please [edit] the outputs requested into your post so that we can see them for ourselves. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Another idea would be to reinstall it as it appears that your installation failed with an error when you chose Downloads as the target directory.

Comment: Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your installation failed mid-process due to your choice to install in the Downloads folder, Attempt installation again and choose a more appropriate location (the default should work fine).

Answer (score 2):

This should work and you can find instructions on how to assign files and create a desktop launcher [here](https://gabstutorials.wordpress.com/2017/06/15/install-and-configure-packet-tracer-7-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

Download Packet Tracer 7 from NetAcad

Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t) and extract the tar file :

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ tar xzvf PacketTracer70_64bit_linux.tar.gz
```

Start the installation :

```
$ sudo ~/Downloads/PacketTracer70/./install
```

You will be ask to accept the terms and select a location to install (press ‘Enter’ to select the default location /opt/pt )

You can launch PT7 by typing ‘packettracer’ in a terminal

Delete the installation files :

```
$ sudo rm -rf ~/Downloads/{PacketTracer70,PacketTracer70_64bit_linux.tar.gz}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and have resolved it, following is what I did in order to resolve the issue. Probably should work for you as well.

navigate to /opt/pt/bin and run the PacketTracer7 file

I got a unable to find or missing libpng12.so.0  when I tried to run the PacketTracer7

locate libpng12.so.0  # I found it in /snap/core/7169/lib/x86_64-linux gnu/libpng12.so.0

packettracer needs that in /usr/lib so issue the following command

sudo ln -s /snap/core/7169/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0

and Thats all, now you just run packettracer it would run. So if you have some other library missing etc just follow the same procedure to solve the problem. Hope this answers your query.